# empty pages in PrestaShop 1.4.3

Tags: php, mysql, security, debugging, prestashop

PrestaShop 1.4.3: when type main page url or any page address, just show empty pages, no errors; right click on any page view source, show just "1". Sure, I know Prestashop 1.4x is old and buggy, but I can't upgrade it fast.

Comment: Edit `prestashop/config/defines.inc.php` set `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to true, and see if shows an error.

Comment: Probably you have a `die()` somewhere that blocks all.

Comment: In which file it could be?

Comment: Good question, I don't know :). Make a 'search all' in the entire site :)